# Where must bu an email password?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, email-spec

What must I change in email_steps.rb except `example@example.com` in line 32?

How can this look at my email without a password?

I don't understan, must I change hier (in **email_steps.rb**) something else and use it like my test (whrite my test hier)?

Or must I write a new test, that will be use the commands from **email_steps.rb**???

Comment: Please provide relevant code from `email_steps.rb`.

Comment: Hier: https://github.com/dalibor/popravi.mk/blob/master/features/step_definitions/email_steps.rb